# use of $ symbol in javascript regular expression?

Tags: javascript

in the following regular expression why are we using $ symbol? what does it mean?
can anyone explain? i have been looking for this for a long time?

```
           function AllowAlphabet(){
           if (!frm.alphabet.value.match(/[a-zA-Z]+$/) && frm.alphabet.value !="")
           {
                frm.alphabet.value="";


                alert("Please Enter only alphabets");
           }
           if(frm.alphabet.value.length > 5)
           alert("max length exceeded");
```

Comment: Then you haven't been looking properly. From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions): *"$ Matches end of input. If the multiline flag is set to true, also matches immediately before a line break character."*. Also a helpful reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dollar sign signifies the end of a line in Regular Expressions.

What it does in this case is make sure that the regex checks that `frm.alphabet.value` contains a-z or A-Z, immediately followed by the line ending. If you removed the dollar character, "abc1337" would be valid input, although even with the dollar characters, without a caret at the start, "1337abc" will be valid input.

Answer (score 2):

`$` binds the expression to the end of the string (also known as an [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)). The matched string must end in upper or lowercase letters.

Though, FWIW, that expression should also be using the start of string anchor (`^`) f they want to make sure it's only letters in the string. (Without it a value of `5abc` would be passing with that regex).

```
var foo = '5abc';
if (foo.match(/[a-zA-Z]$/)) {
  // this block is executed despite the 5 being there.
  console.log('match');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Actually it is not `jQuery` it is **`Regex`**(in your case)
2. `$` - If a dollar sign ($) is at the end of the entire regular expression, *it matches the end of a line*.

Check this [**regexplained**](http://tinyurl.com/jvp6bcg) for easy understanding of your `regex`

Answer (score 0):

`^` and `$` represents the beginnings and endings of a line in regular expressions respectively